# How do I get MQTT topic data from adafruit upon device start up

Tags: ios, mqtt, adafruit

I am building an iphone app which uses MQTT_Client_Foundation(https://github.com/novastone-media/MQTT-Client-Framework)to subscribe and publish to topics on Adafruit.com.
I have it working that it connects and looks for updates when the values are updated on the server and it publishes to the server when a button is tapped.
My problem is that I want to get the current topic values on the server when I open the app without having to wait for then to be updated.
This is the code I have now:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MQTTClient/MQTTClient.h>
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *batteryValueLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *tempValueLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *temperatureValueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *levelValueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tripValueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateValueLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSArray *certificates;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *Fill;


-(IBAction)Turnon:(id)sender;
@end
NSString *trip = @"0";
int trigger =1;
int B = 50;
int T = 90;
MQTTSession *session;
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tempValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 250-(T+45),65, T+45);
    _batteryValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(114, 287, B*1.7, 63);
    NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", T];
    self.temperatureValueLabel.text = myNewString;
    MQTTCFSocketTransport *transport = [[MQTTCFSocketTransport alloc] init];
    transport.host = @"io.adafruit.com";
    transport.port = 1883;
   
    session = [[MQTTSession alloc] init];
    session.userName = @"xxxxxxxxx";
    session.password = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    session.transport = transport;
    session.delegate = self;
```

//MODIFIED CODE HERE FOR /GET

```
     [session connectWithConnectHandler:^(NSError *error) {
   
        if(!error){
            
            [session subscribeToTopic:@"XXXXXX/feeds/+" atLevel:1 subscribeHandler:^(NSError *error, NSArray *gQoss){
                
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Subscription failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Subscription sucessfull! Granted Qos: %@", gQoss);
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

//SEEMS TO ME THAT THEY ARE PASSING A NUMBER NOT A STRING

```
            trip = @"0";
            NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [session publishData:data onTopic:@"gbenna/feeds/temperature/get" retain:NO qos:1 publishHandler:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@", trip);
            NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
                });}
    }];
            }
        else {NSLog(@"[connectWithConnectHandler]Error Connect %@", error.localizedDescription);}
    
    
}];
```

}

```
//this is continuously called and gets data when server values are updated
- (void)newMessage:(MQTTSession *)session
              data:(NSData *)data
           onTopic:(NSString *)topic
               qos:(MQTTQosLevel)qos
          retained:(BOOL)retained
               mid:(unsigned int)mid {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"topic: %@", topic);
    NSLog(@"data:%@", dataString);
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/temperature"]){
        T = [dataString intValue];
        self.temperatureValueLabel.text = dataString;
        self.tempValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 250-(T+45),65, T+45);
        if (T <= 69) {
            _tempValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dk blue rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if ((69< B)&& (B <= 90)) {
            _tempValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if (B > 90) {
            _tempValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red rectangle.png"];
        }
    }
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxxxx/feeds/level"]){
        self.levelValueLabel.text = dataString;}
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxxxx/feeds/date"]){
        self.dateValueLabel.text = dataString;}
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxxxx/feeds/battery"]){
      
        B = [dataString intValue];
        _batteryValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(114, 287, B*1.7, 63);
        if (B <= 20) {
            _batteryValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if ((20< B)&& (B <= 100)) {
            _batteryValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if (B > 100) {
            _batteryValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red rectangle.png"];
        }
    }
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxxxxx/feeds/trip"]){
        self.tripValueLabel.text = dataString;}


}
//when I tap this button the value on the server is updated
-(IBAction)Turnon:(id)sender;{
    if(trigger ==1){
        trip = @"0";
        trigger = 2;
    }
    else if(trigger==2){
        trip = @"100";
        trigger = 1;
    }
    NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [session publishData:data onTopic:@"xxxxxxxxx/feeds/trip" retain:NO qos:1 publishHandler:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", trip);
    NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
}
@end
```

Does anyone know what code and where to put it so that when I open the app it gets the current topic value on the server without waiting for an update?

Comment: Does the Adafruit broker support retained messages?

Comment: can't tell for sure  Hard to get any answers from them.  Can you suggest a way to do what I want and I will try it.

Comment: Publish a message with the retained bit set

Comment: I can't find how to publish a retain flag but they do have what is a /get modifier.  This basically sends a publish to the topic you want the current value for and makes it update with the same value.  Thus as you are subscribed to the same topic it is updated with the same value.  There is an example here: https://gist.github.com/abachman/f6c2c4e1600517f339b32e10ac580c0d and an explination of the /get here: https://io.adafruit.com/api/docs/mqtt.html#adafruit-io-39-s-limitations under the "Using the *get topic".  I have updated my original post to try to get this to work.  seems to use a # tho

Comment: The retained bit is an option when you publish the message, not something you do on the subscribing client side. I suggest you read this: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-8-retained-messages/

Comment: I will look at it but I think they use the /get method to update when there is no new info or when a device launches or comes back on line

Comment: Please do NOT edit the question to include a solution, add it as an answer and you can mark it as accepted. Answered questions rank higher in the search so help more people. Also retained messages is the proper way to do this across all MQTT brokers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226570/discussion-between-user1114881-and-hardillb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work
Here is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MQTTClient/MQTTClient.h>
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *batteryValueLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *tempValueLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *temperatureValueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *levelValueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tripValueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateValueLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSArray *certificates;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *Fill;


-(IBAction)Turnon:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)update:(id)sender;
@end
NSString *trip = @"0";
int trigger =1;
int B = 50;
int T = 90;
MQTTSession *session;
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tempValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 250-(T+45),65, T+45);
    
    NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", T];
    self.temperatureValueLabel.text = myNewString;
    MQTTCFSocketTransport *transport = [[MQTTCFSocketTransport alloc] init];
    transport.host = @"io.adafruit.com";
    transport.port = 1883;
    session = [[MQTTSession alloc] init];
    session.userName = @"xxxxxxxx";
    session.password = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    session.transport = transport;
    session.delegate = self;
    [session connectWithConnectHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if(!error){
                
                [session subscribeToTopic:@"xxxxxxxx/feeds/temperature" atLevel:1 subscribeHandler:^(NSError *error, NSArray *gQoss){
                    
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Subscription failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Subscription sucessfull! Granted Qos: %@", gQoss);
                
                trip = @"0";
                NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [session publishData:data onTopic:@"gbenna/feeds/temperature/get" retain:NO qos:0 publishHandler:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", trip);
                NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
                   }
        }];
                [session subscribeToTopic:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/battery" atLevel:1 subscribeHandler:^(NSError *error, NSArray *gQoss){
                    
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Subscription failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Subscription sucessfull! Granted Qos: %@", gQoss);
                
                trip = @"0";
                NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [session publishData:data onTopic:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/battery/get" retain:NO qos:0 publishHandler:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", trip);
                NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
                    }
        }];
                [session subscribeToTopic:@"xxxxxxxx/feeds/level" atLevel:1 subscribeHandler:^(NSError *error, NSArray *gQoss){
                    
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Subscription failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Subscription sucessfull! Granted Qos: %@", gQoss);
                
                trip = @"0";
                NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [session publishData:data onTopic:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/level/get" retain:NO qos:0 publishHandler:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", trip);
                NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
                    }
        }];
                [session subscribeToTopic:@"gbenna/feeds/date" atLevel:1 subscribeHandler:^(NSError *error, NSArray *gQoss){
            
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Subscription failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Subscription sucessfull! Granted Qos: %@", gQoss);
                
                trip = @"0";
                NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [session publishData:data onTopic:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/date/get" retain:NO qos:0 publishHandler:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", trip);
                NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
                   }
        }];
                [session subscribeToTopic:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/trip" atLevel:1 subscribeHandler:^(NSError *error, NSArray *gQoss){
            
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Subscription failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Subscription sucessfull! Granted Qos: %@", gQoss);
                
                trip = @"0";
                NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [session publishData:data onTopic:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/trip/get" retain:NO qos:0 publishHandler:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", trip);
                NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
                   }
        }];
                }
            else {NSLog(@"[connectWithConnectHandler]Error Connect %@", error.localizedDescription);}
        
        
    }];
   
  
    
    
}

- (void)newMessage:(MQTTSession *)session
              data:(NSData *)data
           onTopic:(NSString *)topic
               qos:(MQTTQosLevel)qos
          retained:(BOOL)retained
               mid:(unsigned int)mid {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"topic: %@", topic);
    NSLog(@"data:%@", dataString);
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx/feeds/temperature"]){
        T = [dataString intValue];
        self.temperatureValueLabel.text = dataString;
        self.tempValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 250-(T+45),65, T+45);
        if (T <= 69) {
            _tempValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dk blue rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if ((69< B)&& (B <= 90)) {
            _tempValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if (B > 90) {
            _tempValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red rectangle.png"];
        }
    }
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx/feeds/level"]){
        self.levelValueLabel.text = dataString;}
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx/feeds/date"]){
        self.dateValueLabel.text = dataString;}
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/battery"]){
      
        B = [dataString intValue];
        self.batteryValueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(332, 250-(B*1.7), 65, B);
        if (B <= 20) {
            _batteryValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if ((20< B)&& (B <= 100)) {
            _batteryValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green rectangle.png"];
        }
        else if (B > 100) {
            _batteryValueLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red rectangle.png"];
        }
    }
    if ([topic isEqualToString:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/trip"]){
        self.tripValueLabel.text = dataString;}


}
-(IBAction)Turnon:(id)sender;{
    if(trigger ==1){
        trip = @"0";
        trigger = 2;
    }
    else if(trigger==2){
        trip = @"100";
        trigger = 1;
    }
    NSData* data = [trip dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [session publishData:data onTopic:@"xxxxxxx/feeds/trip" retain:NO qos:1 publishHandler:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", trip);
    NSLog(@"%d",trigger);
    
}

@end
```

Once connected to the server I subscribed to a topic and then when I was subscribed to that topic I published the /get method for it.  I did this for each topic. and they all update with the last current value for each topic when I launch my app.  I am going to try and see what happens when I come back for being in the background and maybe add a button to update (/get) all topics also.

Thanks for everyone's help.